# plot aggregate grouped by in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, group-by

I have summed a value that I have group by. I would like to plot it.

I grouped by the data which is sorted how I want. Nonetheless, I do not find how to plot it.

I have the following code:

```
subset_sales = sales[sales['Is Good'] == 1].groupby(['Name','Delivery hour', 'Delivery Date'])['Volume'].agg('sum')
```

which gives me the output:

```
 Name      Delivery Hour        Delivery Date

Angela      Morning              Monday       1
                                 Tuesday      2
                                 Wednesday    3
                                 Thursday     5
                                 Friday       2
                              ...
Eva      Afternoon            Monday      7
                              Tuesday     3
                              Wednesday   5
                              Thursday    2
                              Friday      4
Name: Volume, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

I reset the index:

```
subset_sales_2 = subset_sales.reset_index()
```

It gives the following output:

```
      Name Delivery Hour Delivery Date  Volume 
0         Angela               Morning    Monday         1
1         Angela               Morning    Tuesday        2
2         Angela               Morning    Wednesday      3
3         Angela               Morning    Thursday       5
4         Angela               Morning    Friday         2
           ...                 ...           ...           ...
17955     Eva               Afternoon    Monday        7
17956     Eva               Afternoon    Tuesday       3
17957     Eva               Afternoon    Wednesday     5
17958     Eva               Afternoon    Thursday      2
17959     Eva               Afternoon    Friday        4
```

I only manage to get two subpplots. The aim is to plot the volumes for the different delivery hours on the y-axis for Eva and Angela on the same plot with the delivery dates as the x-axis. The expected output is two plots for each delivery (morning and afternoon) with two lines (Eva, and Angela).

I first tried :

```
subset_sales_2.plot()
```

But the output is just one curve. It looks like an aggregate of all the summed volumes.

Finally, I tried:

```
subset_sales_3 = subset_sales_2.loc[(subset_sales_2['Name'] == 'Angela') & (subset_sales_2['Delivery Hour'] == 'Morning')]
subset_sales_3 = subset_sales_3.set_index('Delivery Date')
subset_sales_3['Volume'].plot()

subset_blocks_4 = subset_sales_2.loc[(subset_sales_2['Name'] == 'Eva') & (subset_sales_2['Delivery Hour'] == 'Morning')]
subset_sales_4 = subset_sales_4.set_index('Delivery Date')
subset_sales_4['Volume'].plot()

subset_sales_3['Volume'].plot() + subset_sales_4['Volume'].plot()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'AxesSubplot' and 'AxesSubplot'
```

There is still a chart as an output but the index is wrong because the number of delivery dates is not the same.

I tried:

```
subset_blocks.xs('Morning', level =   1).reset_index().plot()
```

I get one chart with one line for the volume instead of two, one for Eva and one for Angela.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your plot code would be helpful in troubleshooting this.

Comment: I added the plot code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `matplotlib` plotting, multiple metrics are run for each column of data frame/array. Hence, you need wide data instead of long data. Therefore instead of `groupby`, consider `pivot_table` to generate *Angela*, *Eva*, etc. columns. Also, for simpler 2-D (x/y) with one legend plots, the typical plots use one classification column (i.e., only *Delivery Hour* or only *Delivery Date*). But you can extend with subplots for multiple columns. Below shows both approaches.

Additionally, for weekdays, consider using a [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#controlling-behavior) `dtype` to ensure x-axis is not alphabetically ordered but stays in Monday - Friday.

**Random data** *(seeded for reproducibility)*

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype  
...

### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(11052019)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.random.choice(['Angela', 'Eva'], 500),
                          'Delivery Hour': np.random.choice(['Morning', 'Evening'], 500),
                          'Delivery Date': np.random.choice(list(calendar.day_name)[0:5], 500),
                          'Volume': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500)

cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=list(calendar.day_name)[0:5], ordered=True)
random_df['Delivery Date'] = random_df['Delivery Date'].astype(cat_type)
```

**Plotting**

```
# AGGREGATION (WITHOUT 'Delivery Hour')
subset_sales = (random_df.pivot_table(index=['Delivery Date'], 
                                      columns='Name', values='Volume', aggfunc='sum')
                         .reset_index()
                         .set_index('Delivery Date')
                )    

### PLOTTING
subset_sales.plot(kind='line', rot=90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Line Plot Output]

Alternatively, with bar plot:

```
subset_sales.plot(kind='bar', rot=90)
```

[image: Bar Plot Output]

---

However, to integrate the added dimension, *Delivery Hour*, run a `subplots` call, using the `ax` argument of [DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

```
# AGGREGATION (WITH 'Delivery Hour')
subset_sales = (random_df.pivot_table(index=['Delivery Hour', 'Delivery Date'], 
                                      columns='Name', values='Volume', aggfunc='sum')
                         .reset_index()
                         .set_index('Delivery Date')
                )

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5))

(subset_sales[subset_sales["Delivery Hour"] == 'Morning']
      .plot(title = "Morning", rot=90, ax=ax[0])
)

(subset_sales[subset_sales["Delivery Hour"] == 'Evening']
      .plot(title = "Evening", rot=90, ax=ax[1])
)
```

[image: Subplot Output]